# How to export file polygon with date in PyQgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to export my polygon with this file name : yyyymmdd_PVD.gpkg

```
from qgis import processing
import datetime
    
dir = 'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/'+ str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.gpkg'
processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
               {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer(),
               'OUTPUT':dir,
               'LAYER_NAME':'test',
               'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
               'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 61, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 187, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 72, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create layer C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/2023-03-21 17:19:46.771813.gpkg: Unable to load C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/2023-03-21 17 provider
```

Answer (score 3):

You are importing the `datetime` module with `import datetime` but then you try to use a `now()` method from a `date` object/module which does not exist.

You probably meant to use `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: I changed it , but it still get an error

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the date special characters to meet prerequisites for creating folder structures in Windows.

You cannot create folders with characters like `:` or `/`

Another problem you may face, is that the word **`dir`** is reserved in Python, avoid using it as a variable name

Format the date without the character `:`

```
from qgis import processing
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") # or "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
    
archive= f'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/{date}.gpkg'
processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
               {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer(),
               'OUTPUT':archive,
               'LAYER_NAME':'test',
               'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
               'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  it works but one more thing , if i load it, it saves on my downloads.yest but it is not automatically loaded in my qgis , how can i do that ?

Comment: you are using the processing.run tool, for this it only processes, what you can do is change to the processing.runAndLoadResults tool

Comment: flag the answer as correct to help another users.

Comment: To learn more, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

Comment: I tried to modify a couple of times and it gave me an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 63, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Hello Charlie, for this change it is necessary to include editing with the new code for me to understand what you are trying to do. Remember this is a Q&A forum, for a question an answer, for another question a new post